# Excel VBA - Copy Cell from worksheet if another cell has data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code and it works:

```
If Cells(i, 17).Value <> "" Then
    .Range("T" & i).Value = "Not Started"
    .Range("S" & i).Value = "0"
End If
```

Now, I'm trying to tell VBA to not insert "Not Started", but instead insert the value of another cell on a different worksheet.

So, "if there's any data in column 17 (Q), go to column T and insert the data contained in cell "H4" on the tab / sheet called "Summary".

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all you're looking for is

```
If Cells(i, 17).Value <> "" Then
    .Range("T" & i).Value = Sheets("Summary").Range("H4").Value
End If
```